# Preprocess Info.plist with file from Build Phase

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4

I'm trying to preprocess my Info.plist with a file that is generated from a script run in a build phase. Since the file doesn't exist at the beginning of the compile, I receive a warning "C Preprocessor Error: 'file' file not found". Of course the file will exist by the time that it's needed. Is there any way around this?

Comment: I'm more and more convinced that this is a bug (or at least a deficiency) with Xcode. I will file a bug with Apple.

Answer (score 1):

The generated file needs to exist before the target starts. The workaround is to create another target with the sole purpose of generating the preprocess prefix file.

Assuming your main target is 'foo', and using Xcode 4.3:

- Add Target -> Other -> Aggregate (this creates an empty target)
- Add the "run script" phase
- In foo's build phases, reference the new target as a target dependency

From [this blog post](http://www.cimgf.com/2011/02/20/revisiting-git-tags-and-building/) by [Marcus S. Zarra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10673/marcus-s-zarra).